# Regex to delete everything behind first letter

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a regex `\b\d+\K[a-z]` Replace with: `\u$0`

This makes letters in front of numbers caps, for example:

```
123host

1643domain
```

into

```
123Host

1643Domain
```

What I need to figure out now is how can I delete the numbers.

So I need:

```
123host
```

to become

```
host
```

and so on, all entries have a numbers in front of them like this:

```
6410james

599stacks
```

Into

```
james

stacks
```

I tried doing `\b\d+\K[a-z]` replace with nothing, but it just deletes the first letter, I'm a total noob and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can just match `^\d+` and replace with nothing. When you use `\K`, it tells it to not include whatever comes before it in the captured match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply find `\d+` or `[0-9]+` and replace it with an empty string, if all samples have the digits in the start. `^\d+` or `^[0-9]+` would also work fo our cases, however it would not work if we'd have digits [after the letters](https://regex101.com/r/2TS9nb/1/).

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GeJM29/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

---

Comment: But this will remove the numbers from `hello123`, whereas question is having this line `all entries have a numbers infront of them like this`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you probably want to search for is:

```
^[^a-zA-Z]*
```

and then replace with empty string.  This is a literal translation of the requirement to remove every non letter from the start of the string.

### Demo